# jQuery reject certain characters input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, focus

I'm making a system where you press a key and it changes text box. I only want to be able to put the values `X, x, E, e, /`
My current jQuery code is

```
$('.today').keyup(function(e) {
  var self = $(this);
  var currentInput = self.data('number');
  var next = $(currentInput + 1);
  var previous = $(currentInput - 1);
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  var num = self.data('number') + 1;
  var nom = self.data('number') - 1;
  if(('input.today[data-number="' + num +'"]').length && keyCode === 40)
    $('input.today[data-number="' + num +'"]').focus()
  else if(('input.today[data-number="' + nom +'"]').length && keyCode === 38)
    $('input.today[data-number="' + nom +'"]').focus();
  else if(('input.today[data-number="' + num +'"]').length && self.val().length == self.attr('size')) {
    $('input.today[data-number="' + num +'"]').focus();
  }
});
```

I only want the focused box to move if the key up is one of these: `X, x, E, e, /, UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT`. And if the values are not `X, x, E, e, /` then to not write in the box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help:

```
$('.today').keyup(function(e) {
  if(~[38, 39, 40, ...].indexOf(e.keyCode || e.which)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
  ...
}
```

The key there being the call to `e.preventDefault()`.

You also have of the element the keyup event originated in as `e.target`.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

You can examine the key that was pressed to determine how the event should proceed. If you don't want text to appear on certain key presses, then you can either `return false` from the handler, or call `e.preventDefault()`:

```
if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [69, 88, 191]) === -1) { // e, x, / respectively
    e.preventDefault(); // don't print the character
}
```

You can get a list of the JavaScript keycodes here: [Key Codes](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes).